# Saving values to a vector from a loop in MATLab

Tags: matlab, loops, vector, while-loop

I'm trying to save values from a while loop into vectors. I have the following code.

```
Delta_P = 1;

count = 0;

while Delta_P > 0.00001
    x1 = ((y1*p)/(c1*p1));
    x2 = ((y2*p)/(c2*p2));
    c1 = exp(A*x2.^2);
    c2 = exp(A*x1.^2);

    p_update = 1/(y1/(c1*p1)+(y2/(c2*p2)));

    Delta_P = abs(p-p_update);

    p = p_update;

    count = count + 1;
end
```

I need to save p, x1, and x2 into vectors. The loop must also stay in a while loop. I have no idea on how I would go about saving them into vectors.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop change only:

```
.
.
.
x1(count) = ((y1*p)/(c1*p1));
x2(count) = ((y2*p)/(c2*p2));
.
.
.
p(count) = p_update;
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Dans answer - you would need to either:

1. Change the initialisation of count to be count = 1;

or

2. Move the increment of count to be before you use it for x1(count) ....